# Required version of docx4j for jdk 1.4

Tags: docx4j, jdk1.4

What version of DOCX4j is suitable for JDK 1.4 based java compiler. I want to convert a docx file to html file using docx4j jar

Regards
Prasad

Comment: I guess you know this, but that version of Java reached its end of life almost six years ago. You really shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Woah!  That knowledge is lost in the mists of time!

Have a look in http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/archive/

Try say 2.5.0?  Then go earlier or later from there.  Of course, the deps need to be compatible with 1.4 as well.  You can use [JarCheck](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/utils/JarCheck.java) to check those.

You'll need to download/install the JAXB reference implementation (RI), and you'll need to ensure that that also, is compatible with 1.4.  Iirc, there is a question somewhere here on SO as to what is the last version of the RI compatible with 1.5; not sure whether that version also works with 1.4.

Please let us know here what you find, either in a comment or an answer of your own.